Do I need to add Input sanitizer while working with React from with or without React-hook-form? If yes, then how to add it?
I'm working on a React project where I've implemented a form using react-hook-form. While the form works as expected, I'm concerned about the security of user input and want to add input sanitization to prevent potential vulnerabilities like XSS attacks.
Here's a simplified version of my form component:

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

      <input {...register("firstName")} />

      <input {...register("lastName", { required: true })} />

      {errors.lastName && <p>Last name is required.</p>}

      <input {...register("age", { pattern: /\d+/ })} />

      {errors.age && <p>Please enter a number for age.</p>}

      <input type="submit" />

    </form>
  );
}

I've read that input sanitization is crucial for security, but I'm not sure how to integrate it into my form. Could someone please provide guidance on the best practices for implementing input sanitization in a React form? Additionally, are there any recommended libraries or approaches for sanitizing user input in a React application?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can use DOMPurify to sanitise the input:
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

const onSubmit = (data) => {
  const sanitizedData = {
    firstName: DOMPurify.sanitize(data.firstName),
    lastName: DOMPurify.sanitize(data.lastName),
    age: data.age,
  };
};


Thanks for the info. But is this required for security specially when building form with React? Cannot I skip this in React?

@AshfiquzzamanSajal hi, it's not required in react's component level as react uses virtual dom(unless you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML), but this is important if you want to send data to the backend
